# Is there colour schemes tools to integrate with Twitter Bootstrap Less files?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I know that I can include the file `bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less` which I can use to override colors in Twitter Bootstrap css files.

But, isn't there a way that I set less variables using online colour schemes generator on the fly ? such a tool will be so great to start customizing theme for Twitter Bootstrap!

Any known tool there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For css and less outputs i know only one tool : http://www.boottheme.com/#generatetheme
For css only : http://stylebootstrap.info